# getRecordTypeInfosByName()

Tags: apex, record-type

I used recordtypeId == '012A0000000rI1T' in a method to query if my Account recordtype "Practice Account" was what I wanted.

I've been reading that this is not a best practice and I should use something like:

```
Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Practice Account').getRecordTypeId()
```

My question is does getRecordTypeInfosByName() look at the developer name or the record type label? I can't find any info about which it looks at.

Comment: This would take 15s in execute anonymous to check...

Comment: Hi! PM for Apex here. This uses the display label today. We're working on adding a new method that uses the API name soon. Follow the idea for updates https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000K9zoAAC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not entirely clear in the [documentation on the gerRecordTypeInfosByName() method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject_describe), but the documentation does make a mention of using the 'label'

> **getRecordTypeInfosByName()**
>
> Returns a map that matches record labels to their associated record type. The current user is not required to have access to a record type to see it in this map.

I don't know if there are any standard objects that have record type names that include a space, but I know that my org has a few.

Checking my codebase revealed the following line

```
Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Change Order').getRecordTypeId();
```

As API names cannot contain spaces, and I've had this particular line of code in production for coming up on 3 years, we can conclude that the map returned by `getRecordTypeInfosByName()` is indeed keyed on the record type's label.

Comment: Just confirming it does NOT use the DeveloperName and is one of the limitations of this method. There is a 6 year old idea around this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000K9zoAAC

Answer (score 15):

getRecordTypeInfosByName() looks for Label.

After summer '18 preview, Salesforce is going to support `getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()` delivered: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm

Example: (Change your record type *developer name* in below example)

```
system.debug(Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Customer_Success_Support').getRecordTypeId());
```

Comment: A sample code snippet will help.

Comment: Using my example you would do something like this:

System.debug(Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Practice_Account').getRecordTypeId());

returns 012A0000000rI1TIAU

Comment: For using this "getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()" you should maintain your class version atleast 43.